# How to write unit test case for a custom validator for angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

How to write test case for the below method:

```
export class CustomErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStatematcher {
isErrorState(control: FormControl,form:NgForm | FormGroupDirective | null){
return control && control.invalid && control.touched
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of the control and pass your custom validator there. And then assign some value to it and test the expected output.

Here's an example:

```
let control: FormControl;

describe('Phone validator: ', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    control = new FormControl('', [phoneValidator]);
  });

  it('should validate phone', () => {
    control.setValue('not a phone number');
    expect(control.valid).toBe(false); // invalid phone number

    control.setValue('+49123456789');
    expect(control.valid).toBe(true); // valid phone number
  });
});
```